# Mongodb query on all second level documents if any of sub document satisfy condition

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am trying to get `default_billing` from address book in following second level sub document

```
{ 
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a841ac387c7d70ad36f5ce2"), 
        "user_type" : "retail", 
        "first_name" : "Mayank", 
        "last_name" : "Garg", 
        "addressbook" : {
            "5a93d64187c7d71562433a22" : {
                "consignee_name" : "Jerry Day", 
                "first_name" : "Cole", 
                "last_name" : "Bean", 
                "mobile" : "33333333333333", 
                "street_address" : "", 
                "street_address2" : "", 
                "city" : "", 
                "zip_code" : "58694", 
                "select_country" : "India", 
                "default_billing" : true
            }, 
            "5a9400f887c7d70aac2908e2" : {
                "consignee_name" : "Jerry Day", 
                "first_name" : "Cole", 
                "last_name" : "Bean", 
                "mobile" : "33333333333333", 
                "street_address" : "", 
                "street_address2" : "", 
                "city" : "",  
                "select_state" : "Delhi", 
                "zip_code" : "78004", 
                "select_country" : "India"
            }
        }
    }
```

> I tried this

```
db.collection.find( {
 addressbook: {
 $all: [ { "$elemMatch" : { default_billing: true } } ]
 }
 } )
```

Comment: `$elemMatch` will work only on the array.

Comment: Are you open to using aggregation?

Comment: yes that will work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$objectToArray` to make the object array, apply a filter on the array and use `$arrayToObject` convert back the array to object. If no match found in a document, addressbook will be an empty object. We can add `$match` as next stage to remove those if needed.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        addressbook: {
            $objectToArray: '$addressbook'
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        addressbook: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$addressbook',
                as: 'ab',
                cond: {$eq: ['$$ab.v.default_billing', true]}
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        addressbook: {
            $arrayToObject: '$addressbook'
        }
    }
}]);
```